# How to change the default block allocation policy of a file system?

Tags: filesystem

Every file system has some default block allocation policy. For instance unix file system scatters the blocks of a file randomly on disk while ext2,ext3 allocates blocks of a file in block groups. 
Is there any utiltily or system call which can change the default block allocation policy of a file system without modifying the kernel code.

I have created an additional partition in the hard disk and formatted it with ext2 file system. I want to store only multimedia files in this partition. I want to alter the default block allocation policy of ext2 and change it to purely contiguous so that blocks of a multimedia file are stored purely contiguously on my file system partition on hard disk.

Comment: ext2? Just why?

Comment: @Braiam....it can be any file system not juct ext2, its just that I want to do it specifically for ext2.